# Can I stop Resharper creating multiple test sessions?

Tags: resharper

Question pretty much sums it up. I press Ctrl-U,R to run my tests. Most of the time I have a single test session but every so often Resharper adds another. I end up with lots of Resharper test session windows that I have to close one by one. Can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper will create a new session if the existing one is still running, or if it's locked (see the padlock icon). Besides that, it should reuse the existing session - there's nothing you can do, other than use the "Run Current Session" shortcut - check the menu item for what it is, it's different in VS or IntelliJ keyboard layout.

Check to see if your tests have definitely stopped - if they're still running, there might be a bug in your code (or ReSharper's!)

Comment: That's probably the reason then. I didn't know why it sometimes created new sessions. Thanks.